# MongoDB find the specific matches from using $in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and `$in` to find some related documents that share 'tags'.

For example:

```
      Items.find({tags : { $in : ['one','two','three']}}, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
      });
```

I want to find out though specifically which of the values from `$in` actually caused a match (was it one? two?)  Is there a way in Mongo to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just search each doc's `tags` field?  This is not something Mongo is going to tell you, nor should it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is neither a possibility in mongodb nor the nodejs driver to get this information. Mongo is just returning the database entries without any additional data.

You have to iterate through your `docs` and their `tags` via `['one','two','three']` to get this.

Sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I ended up doing.  Mongo always has nice helpful things, wasn't sure maybe through aggregation, if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mongo 2.2 and higher, the aggregation framework could help you

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {$match: { tags: { $in: ['one', 'two', 'three']}}},
  {$unwind: '$tags'},
  {$group: { _id: '$tags', sum: { '$sum': 1 }}}
])
```

which will give you a result where there will be a count of records for each of "one", "two" and "three"